# How to replace ?{GET Variable}= with a /

Tags: php, .htaccess

Guys please help me with this

I want to replace this URL http://www.mywebsite.com/index?type=traveler with http://www.mywebsite.com/index/traveler

http://www.mywebsite.com/index?type=traveler is a hyperlink on some other page

I have tried many things but haven't succeeded till now.

Comment: You want to replace string URL or redirect?

Comment: the query string you are passing let me know what is use for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: @Mohammad, Any thing that works.

Comment: @naveenkumar I am using the query string to differentiate between different customers in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to add a few lines to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index/(.*) index?type=$1 [L]
```

This will use "traveler" as your type parameter.  It will catch any other value and send to the querystring as the type value as well.

Answer (score 0):

Get the url and compare with this condition then include your page and exit.

```
if (strstr($url, 'index/')) {
$urlarr = explode('product/', $url);
$url = $urlarr[1];
$sing_ext = strpos($url, "'");
if ($sing_ext != false) {
    $ur_ar = explode("'", $url);
    $url = $ur_ar[0];
}
$sub_cats_url = $_REQUEST['tag'] = $urlarr[1];

include("product.php");
exit;    }
```